# 301 redirect ALL to a folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I wan't to redirect

```
www.example.com/folder
```

**inlcuding the subfolder and ALL files to land just to**

```
www.example.com/new
```

Just to clarify a bit further, '/folder/blah' should land to only '/new' **NOT** '/new/blah'!

Please help with the redirect..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should rewrite anything under `folder` folder to the `new` folder:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^folder/.+$ /new/ [L,R=301]
```

Examples:

- folder/test
- folder/test.html
- folder/test/test2.html

All will get redirected to `/new/` folder